# instanciar desde varios ficheros, Error CS0103 El nombre 'richTextBox1' no existe en el contexto actual

Tags: c#

no soy un profesional informatico, pero si con muchas horas de vuelo. 
vengo del buen builder borland c++, pero se queda obsoleto y oi que mejor pasarse al c#. 
NO le doy pillao el punto, me parece un rollo. El caso es que quiero manejar MySQL desde c#. 
Me bajo un ejemplo. despues de cambiar varias cosas por las sugerencias, parece que arranca. 
Se me ocurre agregar un RichText para ver un trace, pero no hay manera.

El ejemplo tiene varios ficheros:

1º es el Program.cs que entiendo que no hay que tocar nada, hay un     Application.Run(new Form1()); que lleva a la creacion y se mete en Form1.

2º existe el Form1.Design.cs

```
    namespace ConnectCsharpToMysql
{
//    partial class Form1//<< VERSION ORIGINAL
      public partial class Form1
    {
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, mas codigo,,,,,,,,
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonDesco;
//        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;//<< VERSION ORIGINAL
        public  System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
    }
}
```

3ª el Form1.cs , de momento bien, funciona el Richtext, eso si, despues de iniciar componentes, claro.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConnectCsharpToMysql
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DBConnect dbConnect;

        public Form1()
        {
//            richTextBox1.AppendText("entra InitializeComponent\r\n");//System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

            InitializeComponent();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("sale InitializeComponent\r\n");

            dbConnect = new DBConnect();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("sale new DBConnect()\r\n");
        }

        //Insert button clicked 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

4º DBConectc.cs  y ahora el lio. quiero usar rich para trazar, pero no hay manera.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    //Add MySql Library
    //using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;//<<<<
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace ConnectCsharpToMysql
    {
        class DBConnect
        {
            private SqlConnection connection;
            private string server;
            private string database;
            private string uid;
            private string password;

    //        private Form Form1 = new Form();

            //Constructor
            public DBConnect()
            {
                Initialize();
// ERRORES DEL RICH >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
//            richTextBox1.AppendText("sale Initialize\r\n");//Error CS0103  El nombre 'richTextBox1' no existe en el contexto actual
//            Form1.richTextBox1.AppendText("sale Initialize\r\n");//Error CS0122  'Form1.richTextBox1' no es accesible debido a su nivel de protección
//            Form1.richTextBox1.AppendText("sale Initialize\r\n");//despues de cambiar a public el iniciatecomponet de form1//Error CS0120  Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad 'Form1.richTextBox1' no estáticos
            }

            //Initialize values
            private void Initialize()
            {
                server = "localhost";
                database = "test";
    ,,,,,,,,,,,
```

le di mil vueltas, no encontre ejempllo de intanciar desde varios fichero, 
ya probe con hacerlo todo publico, y con prefijar el objeto,

**ALGUIEN SE SABES LAS PALABRITAS MAGICAS????**

---

**AÑADIDO**
**NADA,,, NO HAY MANERA**
He pelado el problema, en proyecto nuevo, formulario con dos botones y RichText. 
no problema en usar el Rich.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test3{

    public partial class Form1 : Form    {

        public class_Test3A Test3A = new class_Test3A();

        public Form1()        {
            InitializeComponent();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("sale InitializeComponent\r\n");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("pasa boton 1\r\n");
            RichOut("test RichOut(), desde boton 1");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("pasa boton 2\r\n");
            Test3A.Molino();
        }

        public void RichOut(string text)        {//puente, parece que no estatico
            richTextBox1.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

El problema viene ahora, en nuevo archivo, con una clase que intenta escribir en el rich, directa o a traves del puente.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test3
{
    public class class_Test3A    {

        public class_Test3A()   {  }//constructor

        public void Molino()    {
            Form1.richTextBox1.AppendText("test richTextBox1, desde Molino");//Error CS0120  Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad 'Form1.richTextBox1' no estáticos
            Form1.RichOut("test RichOut(), desde Molino");//Error CS0120  Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad 'Form1.richTextBox1' no estáticos
        }
    }
}
```

el problema no viene de ser privados, lo puse todo a publico, hasta una linea en el Form1.Desing.cs
Ni creo que sea por no prefijar los metodos con su objeto. 
La programcion en capas esta muy bien, espero algun dia,,, pero incluso asi, hara falta un sistema de servicio, para "ver" los datos, para mantenimiento y debug. 
Lo de estudiar, ya me descargue varios PDFs, y ya me entere de alguna cosilla. El problema es que todos explican c#, en modo consola, pero no las peculiaridades de windows y visual setudio. 
Y ademas, soy un autodidacta, he dominado el c++ sin estudiarlo de manera metodica y rigurosa, He buscado ejemplos, e hice copia y pega de lo que me interesaba. Pero no encontre a nadie con la necesidad de actuar con formularios desde otros objetos.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hay un monton de errores de concepto, y no se por donde empezar... podria poner una respuesta, pero te dejaria con mas dudas que certezas. Estas siguiendo algun tutorial? todo lo que hiciste para instaciar el textbox no parece correcto. Este solo se pone en el form, nada por codigo y ya queda.

Comment: Estas usando una clase y la clase no sabe que existe el form a menos que le pases una referencia al mismo. Es igual que en c++, las clases solo conocen otras clases si les dices cuales son. podrias pasarle el textbox a tu clase, pero mejor seria que los metodos devolvieran lo que paso.

Comment: Estas usando winforms quiero suponer no? creo que te ira mejor buscando un tutorial y empezando de 0. Si no, ataquemos los problemas de a 1. Tu primer problema seria, como hacer que un textbox muestre algo.

Comment: Gbianchi: si, mire como preguntar. lo que no tengo claro es si te estoy respondiendo a ti, parece que respondiste 3 veces. . . 
¿Como que parar la clase no existe el form?, para eso lo hago publico, incluso lo prefijo con la clase a la que pertenece,,, . . . 
En C++ usaba los includes, para informar en un fichero de lo que hay en otros.  ¿que fue de ellos?. . . 
la cosa se podria resumir en, hay algun ejemplo de como usar utilidades de formulario desde varios ficheros?

Comment: No respondi. Te deje 3 comentarios. Y no, que sea publico no implica visibilidad del mismo. Lee sobre conceptos de objetos en .net o java. Y creo que em c++ era lo mismo. El include agregaba archivos con funcionalidad. Aca se hace con import pero no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Perdon aca se usa using.

Comment: Lee sobre programación en capas, no deberías acceder a la capa de presentación en la capa de datos.

Comment: @shop350 creo que el problema es todavia mas alla de capas de datos o de presentacion, es de conocimiento de teoria de objetos.

Comment: sigo peleando, añadi ejemplo resumido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema principal es pensar que el formulario es otra cosa, y no una clase (un objeto).. y realmente es lo mismo.. lo que pasa es que tiene un componente visual, pero no es algo que realmente impacte en lo que queres hacer.

Los ejemplos suelen ser de consola porque son para explicar el lenguaje. La parte visual, se estudia en otros lados tal vez, pero no deja de ser algo similar su manejo.

Es mas, todos los componentes visuales, son clases que se pueden instanciar y crear en tu formulario (y practicamente, es lo que hace el constructor en windows forms).

Ahora, como mini ejemplo de lo que queres hacer no necesitas mas nada que lo que tenes, veamos un ejemplo de como llenar un textbox desde una clase, de dos formas:

vamos a crear un form, y ponerle un textbox y dos botones.

Tambien, vamos a crear la siguiente clase:

```
class TestClass
{

    public string DevolverTexto()
    {
        return "esto solo devuelve un texto";
    }

    public void EscribirTexto(TextBox t)
    {
        t.Text = "aca la clase escribio directamente!!!";
    }
}
```

Cuando generes esa clase, va a mostrar un error sobre `TextBox`, porque necesitas decirle que es.. para eso, hay que agregar arriba la siguiente linea:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Listo la clase, ya no tiene errores.

Hacemos doble click sobre el boton1 que creamos antes, (eso va a generar automaticamente el evento click) y agregamos este código:

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
textBox1.Text = t.DevolverTexto();
```

Hacemos lo mismo que antes sobre el boton2, y agregamos este codigo:

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
t.EscribirTexto(textBox1);
```

Ahi te genere dos formas distintas de pasarle de una clase un texto a un textbox. En general, se usa siempre la primer version, pero yo queria mostrarte que hay otras formas. Tambien podrias mandar el form, buscar el textbox y escribir alli. Pero es solamente complicar mucho mas, algo que se hace mucho mas simple.

Comment: gracias gbianchi, acabo de probarlo y funciona, tal cual lo has explicado. A mi no se me habria ocurrido, ya puedo avanzar, pero no te vayas muy lejos,,,

Comment: Deja de tenerle miedo al form. Estudia teoria de objetos, que es en realidad lo que te falta. Los forms, son objetos.. con una patita visual.. pero no dejan de ser objetos.. podrias usar todo en consola, no serviria para nada, pero podrias...